# Rails index action with a WHERE clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying learn Rails so I know there are some simple concepts I could be missing.

I have a list of staff, each belonging to a given project. Users who log into the system should only view/manage staff belonging to their project (users are also attached to a given project). This means I have project_id in both User and Staff models.

I want  current_user to only see records from his/her own project. 
I have implemented the authentication system in Michael Hartl's book, so I have a current_user method already defined and working.

Here is my index action:

```
def index
@staffs = Staff.where("current_user.project_id = ?", 'staff.project_id') 
end
```

However, I get an error:

```
no such column: current_user.project_id
```

I am out of ideas. How can I implement this?

Comment: Use `Staff.where("project_id = ?", current_user.project_id)`

Comment: That works! Thank you. How can I make it into a global before_action method to use it in every controller?

Comment: You could create a helper method that could return the query. And then the helper method would be available throughout the controller and it's corresponding views

Comment: I've added an example to show how you can use this to add options for a <select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do:

```rb
def index
    @staffs = Staff.where(project_id: current_user.project_id)
end
```

This will execute the sql code `select … from staff where staff.project_id = 123;`, assuming the value of `current_user.project_id` is 123. This is happening because  the where method takes care of mapping the key you give (project_id) to the value (the value of current_user.project_id).

The sql that would come from your where method would be `select … from staff where current_user.project_id = "staff.project_id";`. The database column should be the first part of the where method, and the value to be the second part.

You could add this to you base controller (ApplicationController) to make it available everywhere, something like:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :current_staff

    def index
    end

    def current_staff
        @staffs = Staff.where(project_id: current_user.project_id) if current_user # make sure user is signed in
    end
end
```

If you want to use this in a select you could add a helper method like this:

```rb
module ApplicationHelper
    def options_for_staff_projects_select(selected = nil)
        project_ids = @staffs.collect(:project_id) # get list of project ids from staff
        options = Project.where(id: project_ids).map { |x| [x.name, x.id] }

        options_for_select options, selected
    end
end

# in your form call:
<%= f.select :project_id, options_for_staff_projects_select(model.project_id), include_blank: 'Choose Project' %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot too @jonathan-bennet

Comment: Hi, just a question on the implementation: what becomes of the `index` action since its implementation is now in the `current_staff` method? Should I revert to `@staffs=Staff.all`?

Comment: Updated answer. The index action would still need to exist to work right, but it would be empty unless you were doing more down the road.

Answer (score 1):

```
Staff.where("current_user.project_id = ?", 'staff.project_id')
```

here `current_user.project_id` is not a column for Staff model. In active record `where` is expecting the first argument to be the column name of given model. So here model is `Staff` and column name you have to check is `project_id` and conditional value is `current_user.project_id` So you have to use condition like below.

```
Staff.where("project_id = ?", current_user.project_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have learnt a lot. Can I cascade it down further to `collection_select` in the `staffs/new` page, to only list the projects `current_user` is associated with? I am trying something like:  `<%= form.select :project_id, options_for_select([["Choose Project", "0"]] + Project.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id] if Project.find_by_id(x.id) == current_user.project_id }), {}%>` . Am only getting a blank options though